# "Convert" Entity Framework program to raw SQL

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I used Entity Framework to create a prototype for a project and now that it's working I want to make the program ready for production.

I face many challenges with EF, the biggest one being the concurrency management (it's a financial software).

Given that it seems to have no way to handle pessimistic concurrency with EF, I have to switch to stored procs in SQL.

To be honest I'm a bit afraid of the workload that may represent.

I would like to know if anybody have been in the same situation before and what is the best strategy to convert a .net code using EF to raw SQL.

Edit: 
I'm investigating CLR but it's not clear if pessimistic concurency can be manage with it. is it an option more interesting than TSQl in this case ? It would allow me to reuse part of my C# code and structure of function calling another functions, if I understand well.

Comment: What version of Entity Framework are you using? Also are you using code first, database first or model first?  No matter what the answer is you can still use EF just depends on how much work it will be.  We use Code First EF 5 and still do pessimistic concurrency on CUD but not reads.

Comment: I'm using EF 6 model first. How do you do Pessimistic concurency with EF?

Comment: It's a little complex but we use EF for everything but updating SQL Server.  We do that with T-SQL but still using EF entity tracking.  I'll add an answer to show.

Comment: You can enclose all business transactions (or units of work) in one `TransactionScope` with a high isolation level (e.g. serializable, or even repeatable read).

Comment: I was thinking about that Gert, the question is: if in a TSQL Transaction I call several CLRs, all the rows using on thoses CLR stored procedures are gonna be locked too ? ( that the behavior i need)

Comment: CLR in the database will fall under the TransactionScope. Further, I think [this incredible blog](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2012/09/entity-framework-and-pessimistic-concurrency/) tells you all you need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was there and the good news is you don't have to give up Entity Framework if you don't want to.  The bad news is you have to update the database yourself.  Which isn't as hard as it seems.  I'm currently using EF 5 but plan to go to EF 6.  I don't see why this still wouldn't work for EF 6.

First thing is in the constructor of the DbContext cast it to IObjectContextAdapter and get access to the ObjectContext.  I make a property for this

```
public virtual ObjectContext ObjContext
{
    get
    {
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
    }
}
```

Once you have that subscribe to the SavingChanges event - this isn't our exact code some things are copied out of other methods and redone.  This just gives you an idea of what you need to do.

```
ObjContext.SavingChanges += SaveData;

private void SaveData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var context = sender as ObjectContext;
    if (context != null)
    {
        context.DetectChanges();
        var tsql = new StringBuilder();
        var dbParams = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();

        var deletedEntites = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Deleted);
        foreach (var delete in deletedEntites)
        {
            // Set state to unchanged - so entity framework will ignore
            delete.ChangeState(EntityState.Unchanged);
            // Method to generate tsql for deleting entities
            DeleteData(delete, tsql, dbParams);
        }

        var addedEntites = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added);
        foreach (var add in addedEntites)
        {
            // Set state to unchanged - so entity framework will ignore
            add.ChangeState(EntityState.Unchanged);
            // Method to generate tsql for added entities
            AddData(add, tsql, dbParams);
        }

        var editedEntites = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified);
        foreach (var edit in editedEntites)
        {
            // Method to generate tsql for updating entities
            UpdateEditData(edit, tsql, dbParams);
            // Set state to unchanged - so entity framework will ignore
            edit.ChangeState(EntityState.Unchanged);
        }
        if (!tsql.ToString().IsEmpty())
        {
            var dbcommand = Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
            dbcommand.CommandText = tsql.ToString();

            foreach (var dbParameter in dbParams)
            {
                var dbparam = dbcommand.CreateParameter();
                dbparam.ParameterName = dbParameter.Key;
                dbparam.Value = dbParameter.Value;
                dbcommand.Parameters.Add(dbparam);
            }
            var results = dbcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Why we set the entity to unmodified after the update because you can do

```
var changed properties = edit.GetModifiedProperties();
```

to get a list of all the changed properties.  Since all the entities are now marked as unchanged EF will not send any updates to SQL.

You will also need to mess with the metadata to go from entity to table and property to fields.  This isn't that hard to do but messing the metadata does take some time to learn.  Something I still struggle with sometimes. I refactored all that out into an IMetaDataHelper interface where I pass it in the entity type and property name to get the table and field back - along with caching the result so I don't have to query metadata all the time.

At the end the tsql is a batch that has all the T-SQL how we want it with the locking hints and containing the transaction level.  We also change numeric fields from just being set to nfield = 10 but to be nfield = nfield + 2 in the TSQL if the user updated them by 2 to avoid the concurrency issue as well.

What you wont get to is having SQL locked once someone starts to edit your entity but I don't see how you would get that with stored procedures as well.

All in all it took me about 2 solid days to get this all up and running for us.